# Interfacing barcode scanner with microcontroller

Tags: c#, serial-port, usb, .net-micro-framework

I am doing a project involving barcode scanner, netduino plus 2(microcontroller). I came across different types of interfaces(pin standard used such as USB etc..) for barcode scanners which are Keyboard wedge, RS232, USB (which again acts as keyboard wedge or RS232). I shortlisted datalogic QW2170 (barcode scanner) which supports both USB and RS 232. The USB interfacing is of plug-n-play type. I was wondering if i can use USB (use usb cable from barcode scanner to connect to netduino plus 2) interfacing to capture the stream of data coming from barcode scanner after scanning barcode (to be specific 1D barcode) and save it in the microsd card (netduino plus 2 has a slot for microsd card upto 2 GB) or do i need to use a RS 232 interfacing for this purpose.

Comment: In which part are you planning to use C#?

Comment: You will probably get better answers if you post it to electronics.stackexchange.com

Comment: The microcontroller which i mentioneed is built on netmf (.NET micro framework) and for programming purpose i would use c#.

Comment: you should definitely try http://electronics.stackexchange.com/. Anyways, I too would suggest RS232 one, as most uC have builtin support for serial ports, and for USB you usually will need some additional chips. But, well, I'm no expert in that topic:)

Answer (score 1):

You'll want the RS232 reader - the microcontroller you mention doesn't appear to have any sort of the host-mode USB functionality required to attach a USB reader. As noted, I'm sure you'd get more input at electronics.stackexchange.com